# Background disappear .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, background, styles

I just finished my `.htaccess` file, only rewriting to a nicer URL, but with no reason the background disappeared. If I access with the ugly old URL the background is there.

```
<html...
...
<style type='text/css'>
body { color:#FFF;background:#444 url(office_1.png); }
body { margin:0;padding:0; }
</style>
</head>
```

The `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule download/(.*)/u_id/(.*)/id/(.*)/n/(.*)$ download.php?on=$1&u_id=$2&id=$3&n=$4
RewriteRule download/(.*)/u_id/(.*)/id/(.*)/n/(.*)/$ download.php?on=$1&u_id=$2&id=$3&n=$4
RewriteRule download/(.*)/u/(.*)/id/(.*)/n/(.*)$ download.php?on=$1&u_id=$2&id=$3&n=$4
RewriteRule download/(.*)/u/(.*)/id/(.*)/n/(.*)/$ download.php?on=$1&u_id=$2&id=$3&n=$4
```

The `.htaccess` rule is working, but why my background disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

The URI is relative, so it is looking for the image in

```
/your/nice/uri/office_1.png
```

Not in

```
/office_1.png
```

The usual fix is to start the image path with a / as I have in the above example to make it relative to the root of the site.

```
url(/office_1.png);
```